# response.status_code is 200, but response.content is empty

Tags: python, locust

I'm working with Locust for load testing a few APIs, below is what the locust file (locustfile.py) looks like:

```
class MyTests(TaskSet):

def on_start(self):
    print("Starting tests")

def get_something(self):
    with self.client.get("some_baseuri" + "some_basepath", catch_response=True) as response:
        print("Response code: {}".format(response.status_code))
        print("Response body: {}".format(response.content))

@task(1)
def my_task(self):
    self.get_something()


class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = MyTests
```

Here's how I trigger my tests:

```
locust -f locustfile.py --no-web --clients=1 --hatch-rate=10 --host=http://127.0.0.1 --num-request=2 --print-stats --only-summary
```

The problem is, in logs, `response.status_code` is printed as 200, but `response.content` happens to be empty. When I hit the same API using Postman, I see a proper response body in the response as expected. This looks like a strange issue which blocks me from calling another API which is dependent on the `get_something()` method since the other API takes some data from `get_something()` method as an input.

Comment: did you test url with differen tool ? maybe it always returns empty content.

Comment: @furas Yes, I tested the same URL with Postman, it gives proper response content in the response body.

Comment: I think there should be ```response._content```. Can you check what response you get?

Comment: `response._content` works! And so does `response.text`, but I wonder why the IDE would show `content` in suggestions after typing `response.`.

Comment: did you find the answer, I meet the same problem and _content is "bound method FastResponse._content of <locust.contrib.fasthttp.ResponseContextManager object at 0x....>>"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locust's default HTTP client is Requests.

Requests gives you several ways to access response content:

- for decoding the content as plain text, use `response.text`
- for decoding the content as json, use `response.json()`
- for accessing the content as binary data, use `response.content`
- for the raw socket response, use `response.raw`

This is explained in much more detail under the "Response Content" section of the Requests docs: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content